Should I make a tapered groove on shaft for retention ring?
In a design I have a steel shaft that is connected to a disc-kind of a rotor (aluminum). The shaft is in form of double-D for torque transfer. Now I need prevent shaft from sliding, so I want to use a retention ring.
But I also need this ring to ensure constant force is applied to the rotor, so wouldn't be wiggling with the ring inside the groove, even if the clearance is very small.
How do I do that? Should I make a tapered groove to make the retention ring slide on it and this way transfer it's spring force to the rotor?

please draw a diagram

Don't mess with the retention clip; leave it to do its job. Use a suitable spring and a washer/spacer between the retention clip and the rotor. The washer will also help you compress the spring while you're putting on that retention ring. Then you will be sure of constant pressure on the rotor.
edit: Use a disc or dome spring.

Rich's answer is the typical solution for applying a smallish seating force. You can find it used on small chain saw drives, for instance. But interestingly, it is normally used to facilitate or accommodate some wobble or axial compliance, not to prevent it. If you want a rigid connection between the shaft and the disc, you need some sort of quality hub to press on the shaft, and then flange the disc to the hub. Another option is to use a set screw. But then you want a single D and run the screw opposite to the flat or two screws at 45 to the flat.

Thank you. What's quality uub?
